# Simple SDL_GetTimer() usage - why isn't it working?

Tags: c++, timer, sdl

I've tried to use SDL_GetTimer() to make action after passing 1000ms using this piece of code:

```
while(1)
{
    int tajmer;
    int czas = SDL_GetTicks();
     tajmer = SDL_GetTicks() - czas;
        if(tajmer > 1000)
        {
        MoveUp();
        czas = SDL_GetTicks();
        }
}
```

But it causes my program to crash. Any ideas why, or how to implement simple timer correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the loop runs, czas is updated to the current time.
Solution: Move it out of the loop.

```
int czas = SDL_GetTicks();
while(1)
{
    int tajmer;
    tajmer = SDL_GetTicks() - czas;
    if(tajmer > 1000)
        {
        MoveUp();
        czas = SDL_GetTicks();
        }
}
```

However what you are trying to accomplish could possibly be done in a better way using built in timers:
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer

Edit:

Example using SDL_AddTimer.

```
Uint32 my_callbackfunc(Uint32 interval, void *param);

int main() {
    ... // don't forget to SDL_Init
    ...
    SDL_AddTimer(1000, my_callbackfunc, NULL);
    ...
}

Uint32 my_callbackfunc(Uint32 interval, void *param)
{
    MoveUp();
    return(1000); // or however long to wait before my_callbackfunc should run.
}
```

If you are currently using classes and want to call a class's method called MoveUp() then perhaps:

```
class example {
    ...
    void start_moving() {
        SDL_AddTimer(1000, my_callbackfunc, (void*)this);
    }
    ...
    public void MoveUp() {
       ...
    }
}

Uint32 my_callbackfunc(Uint32 interval, void *param) {
    ((example*)param)->MoveUp();
    return (1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, your solution doesn't work, it still crashes ;D It's not the issue though, because Bozemoto's way seems to be working (well, not as I expected, but still ;D).
BTW: I heard about SDL_AddTimer and even tried to use it, but I suppose I'm too stupid, so here's my request: could you tell me how to use timer to "MoveUp()" after 1s? :D

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on Yujin Wus answer you can also do something like this.

```
int timer = 0;
int ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
while(true)
{
    timer += SDL_GetTicks() - ticks;
    ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
    if(timer >= 1000)
    {
        timer -= 1000;
        MoveUp();
    }
}
```

Or something like this

```
const int DELAY = 1000;
int timer = SDL_GetTicks() + DELAY;
while(true)
{
    if(timer - SDL_GetTicks() <= 0)
    {
        timer += DELAY;
        MoveUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works somehow, but the problem is I have to be moving my mouse constantly in order to "execute" it ;D I believe it's my program fault, though.

Comment: Try and see if it updates when you press on the keyboard as well. If so it's because the event queue needs elements in it to have elements in it to update the time. Weird bug if that's the case.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Pushing an event by SDL_PushEvent constantly seems to work, but I believe it's not the smartest solution. Thanks again.